# parse and find information of process with UID in ksh or bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
Alexey:Desktop Alexey$ ps -xla
UID   PID  PPID  F CPU PRI NI     SZ   RSS     WCHAN     S  ADDR TTY   TIME   CMD
0     1    0  80004004   0  31  0  2508844   3720 -   Ss   0  ??   0:04.39 /sbin/launchd
501    11    1   4004   0  33  0  2526496   4772 -    Ss   0 ??    0:00.31 /usr/libexec/UserEventA
        ...
        ...
```

I'm writing script that shows information of process of user that I type in shell

```
read userid
```

command `ps -xla` show full information of processes

I need to parse this output and find strings with UID=$userid

Please,help! Have to find best and simple solution, maybe grep or sed or awk or maybe other solution that will work 100 % almost everywhere. Write please some variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
read userid  
pgrep -fl -U $userid
```

or more complete :

```
read userid  
ps -u $userid -la
```

or

```
ps auxw |
    awk -v user=$USER '
        NR==1{
            for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="USER") {
                col=i
             }
        }
        NR>1 && $col==user
    '
```

or if you want `ps -la` :

```
ps -la | awk -v uid=1000 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="UID"){col=i}} NR>1 && $col==uid'
```

---

If you need to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) in the output, you may use a special regex trick to don't display `grep` process itself :

```
ps -u $userid -la | grep '[f]oobar'
```

Comment: but 
`ps -u $userid -le` 
prints the same as `ps -le`.

`ps -u 162103 -le`
prints information about process with UID=162103 AND others like 157654
but i want only 162103

Answer (score 0):

ps has the `-U` option for filtering based on user-ids. You also has to remove the `-x` option.

```
ps -Uuser_name -la
```

Comment: but 
`ps -u $userid -le` 
prints the same as `ps -le`.

`ps -u 162103 -le`
prints information about process with UID=162103 AND others like 157654
but i want only 162103

Comment: -U userlist -> Select by real user ID (RUID) or name. It selects the processes whose real user name or ID is in the userlist list. The real user ID identifies the user who created the process, see getuid(2).